# Increment last number of first line in file

Tags: bash, shell

I want to write a shell script which can increment the last value of the first line of a certain file structure:

**File-structure:**

```
p cnf integer integer   
integer integer ... 0
```

**For Example**:

```
p cnf 11 9   
1 -2 0  
3 -1 5 0
```

**To:**

```
p cnf 11 10   
1 -2 0  
3 -1 5 0
```

The dots should stay the same.

Comment: You mean you want *somebody else* to write it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you could use `perl`:

```
perl -pe  's/(-*\d+)$/$1+1/e' if $. == 1' inputfile
```

Here `(-*\d+)$` is capturing integer value(optionally negative) at the end of the line and `e` flag allows the execution of code before replacement,  so the value increments.

Comment: Use `perl -pe  's/(\S+)$/$1+1/e if $. == 1' inputfile` in case the integer is < 0. The OP showed a few negative numbers as examples of integers.

Answer (score 1):

With GNU awk:

```
awk 'NR==1{$NF++} {print}' file
```

or

```
awk 'NR==1{$NF++}1' file
```

Output:

```
p cnf 11 10
1 -2 0  
3 -1 5 0
```

`$NF` contains last column.